# htlatex gives me a lot of "random" errors

Tags: tex4ht, htlatex

I'm using `htlatex` to convert LaTeX into HTML and I'm getting errors on things that I haven't specified, such as my own environments.

An example is `\def\inline{\lstinline[style=inlineStyle]}` which lets me write:

`\inline{x == 10}`

I'm also using it like this:

`\inline!new[]{}!`

This is just one example, I've got tons of different environments like this. The error I'm getting on this is:

> ? ! Missing } inserted. 
>                   } l.223 \inline!new[]
>                      {}!

**So I want to know** if there is an *"Silent"*-flag that I can use when converting using `htlatex`? So I don't have to press and hold `Enter` for 1 minute during the conversion.

Comment: you can a;ways respond with s to a tex ? error prompt and it will go into scroll mode and not ask again. but if you are using a lot of listings/verbatim macros best would be to define matching configuration in htlatex so that it knows.

Comment: Don't ignore errors, correct them. Also better don't use braces (`{..}`) to surround the argument of your code. That this works (sometimes) is an experimental feature of `\lstinline` which can break easily.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, Break in which way? I've been using that throughout the entire book that I've written. It seems it complains about code that are inside the listings.. Shouldn't it just ignore that?!

Comment: I think I narrowed it down to when I use `\lstdefinelanguage` and then include it with `alsolanguage=` it gives me these errors.

Comment: Seems it doesn't like this particular line: `otherkeywords={[, ]}` I want highlighting on `new[]`, that's why I have that, but it seems like that is causing the problems.

Comment: The braces after `\lstinline` looks like normal argument braces but there aren't. E.g. `\lstinline{\begin{center}}` will not work as expected: the *first* closing brace ends the argument of `\lstinline`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, Right, But when I use braces with lstinline, I do `!!` instead of `{}`

Comment: Your first example (`\inline{x == 10}`) uses braces.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, You missunderstand, when I do `\inline{x==10}` the intent is to get `x==10` printed, I never use braces inside, do you understand?